# Configuration dialog is running again due to some missing parameters

Tags: perl, cpan

Whenever I start my cpan using

```
perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

I get the following message

```
Sorry, we have to rerun the configuration dialog for CPAN.pm due to
some missing parameters...  Will write to
 <</home/chankey/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm>>



The following questions are intended to help you with the
configuration. The CPAN module needs a directory of its own to cache
important index files and maybe keep a temporary mirror of CPAN files.
This may be a site-wide or a personal directory.



I see you already have a  directory
    /home/chankey/.cpan
Shall we use it as the general CPAN build and cache directory?

 <cpan_home>
CPAN build and cache directory? [/home/chankey/.cpan] 

Unless you are accessing the CPAN on your filesystem via a file: URL,
CPAN.pm needs to keep the source files it downloads somewhere. Please
supply a directory where the downloaded files are to be kept.

 <keep_source_where>
Download target directory? [/home/chankey/.cpan/sources] 

 <build_dir>
Directory where the build process takes place? [/home/chankey/.cpan/build] 

Normally CPAN.pm keeps config variables in memory and changes need to
be saved in a separate 'o conf commit' command to make them permanent
between sessions. If you set the 'auto_commit' option to true, changes
to a config variable are always automatically committed to disk.

 <auto_commit>
Always commit changes to config variables to disk? [no] 

CPAN.pm can limit the size of the disk area for keeping the build
directories with all the intermediate files.

 <build_cache>
Cache size for build directory (in MB)? [100] 

The CPAN indexes are usually rebuilt once or twice per hour, but the
typical CPAN mirror mirrors only once or twice per day. Depending on
the quality of your mirror and your desire to be on the bleeding edge,
you may want to set the following value to more or less than one day
(which is the default). It determines after how many days CPAN.pm
downloads new indexes.

 <index_expire>
Let the index expire after how many days? [1] 

By default, each time the CPAN module is started, cache scanning is
performed to keep the cache size in sync. To prevent this, answer
'never'.

 <scan_cache>
Perform cache scanning (atstart or never)? [atstart] 

To considerably speed up the initial CPAN shell startup, it is
possible to use Storable to create a cache of metadata. If Storable is
not available, the normal index mechanism will be used.

Note: this mechanism is not used when use_sqlite is on and SQLLite is
running.

 <cache_metadata>
Cache metadata (yes/no)? [yes] 

The CPAN module can detect when a module which you are trying to build
depends on prerequisites. If this happens, it can build the
prerequisites for you automatically ('follow'), ask you for
confirmation ('ask'), or just ignore them ('ignore').  Choosing
'follow' also sets PERL_AUTOINSTALL and PERL_EXTUTILS_AUTOINSTALL for
"--defaultdeps" if not already set.

Please set your policy to one of the three values.

 <prerequisites_policy>
Policy on building prerequisites (follow, ask or ignore)? [follow] 

Every Makefile.PL is run by perl in a separate process. Likewise we
run 'make' and 'make install' in separate processes. If you have
any parameters (e.g. PREFIX, UNINST or the like) you want to
pass to the calls, please specify them here.

If you don't understand this question, just press ENTER.

Typical frequently used settings:

    PREFIX=~/perl    # non-root users (please see manual for more hints)

 <makepl_arg>
Parameters for the 'perl Makefile.PL' command? [INSTALLDIRS=site] 

Parameters for the 'make' command? Typical frequently used setting:

    -j3              # dual processor system (on GNU make)

 <make_arg>
Your choice: [] 

Parameters for the 'make install' command?
Typical frequently used setting:

    UNINST=1         # to always uninstall potentially conflicting files

 <make_install_arg>
Your choice: [] 

A Build.PL is run by perl in a separate process. Likewise we run
'./Build' and './Build install' in separate processes. If you have any
parameters you want to pass to the calls, please specify them here.

Typical frequently used settings:

    --install_base /home/xxx             # different installation directory

 <mbuildpl_arg>
Parameters for the 'perl Build.PL' command? [--installdirs site] 

Parameters for the './Build' command? Setting might be:

    --extra_linker_flags -L/usr/foo/lib  # non-standard library location

 <mbuild_arg>
Your choice: [] 

Do you want to use a different command for './Build install'? Sudo
users will probably prefer:

    su root -c ./Build
 or
    sudo ./Build
 or
    /path1/to/sudo -u admin_account ./Build

 <mbuild_install_build_command>
or some such. Your choice: [./Build] 

Parameters for the './Build install' command? Typical frequently used
setting:

    --uninst 1                           # uninstall conflicting files

 <mbuild_install_arg>
Your choice: [] 



If you're accessing the net via proxies, you can specify them in the
CPAN configuration or via environment variables. The variable in
the $CPAN::Config takes precedence.

 <ftp_proxy>
Your ftp_proxy? [] 

 <http_proxy>
Your http_proxy? [] 

 <no_proxy>
Your no_proxy? [] 


Now you need to choose your CPAN mirror sites.  You can let me
pick mirrors for you, you can select them from a list or you
can enter them by hand.

Would you like me to automatically choose the best CPAN mirror
sites for you? (This means connecting to the Internet and could
take a couple minutes) [yes] 

Searching for the best CPAN mirrors (please be patient) ...
................................................................................................. done!

New urllist
  ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.funet.fi/pub/languages/perl/CPAN/
  ftp://mirror.tje.me.uk/pub/mirrors/ftp.cpan.org/
  ftp://cpan.fiat-tux.fr/
  ftp://cpan.etla.org/pub/CPAN/
  ftp://ftp.hostingromania.ro/mirrors/ftp.cpan.org/

Please remember to call 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 29432).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/chankey/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y] 
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9456)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install Task::Catalyst::Tutorial
```

Why is it running configuration dialog every time? What parameters are missing? How to correct them so that it doesn't ask for the same thing again and again?

System: Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you do

```
o conf commit
```

as instructed? This saves the configuration to `/home/chankey/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`. If so, you might want to check for permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check whether your `~/.cpan` directory exists.
2. Who is owns it and what permissions it has. If you happened to use `sudo cpan`, this directory could be created as owned by root and is now inaccessible without root privileges.